# Iterate through array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects:

> [{"score":131,"skin":"player_main","created_at":"2016-12-13 19:40:44","name":"Bajabongo95"},{"score":10,"skin":"player_main","created_at":"2016-12-13 19:40:32","name":"Bajabongo95"}]

How I supposted to itterate through this?

I tried with:

```
result.forEach(function(element, i) {
    console.log(element.score);
});
```

and this:

```
for (var key in result) {
    console.log(key, result[key]);
}
```

None of this works. It gives me indexes or every letter (and letter as key), or an error:

> forEach is not a function

How I can itterate this objects and get access to specified data?

Comment: Your first solution will work. You have a bug elsewhere meaning that `result` is not an `Array`.

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` show?  Did you forget to `JSON.parse(result)`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat yep, forgot to parse. Thanks guys.